# How to make background picture maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

Effect : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZvymg
Desired Effect : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpJWXm

Open the picture to the biggest point then minimize your browser.

How do I make it so the entire background image resizes when the browser gets smaller(minimize)? This is what happens in the "Desired Effect" but in the "Effect" when I use background it doesn't resize.

```
<header>
  <div class="image"></div>
<header>

html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/er5sypbyluenzco/Its%20ok.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at 
[**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting background-size

```
.background {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/er5sypbyluenzco/Its%20ok.jpeg");
  background-size:100% 100%; /*this one*/

}
```

Comment: @user7422199: you are welcome ... please accept the answer... if you are happy with it.

Comment: background-size: cover; is a bit shorter one

Comment: in case of cover.. some part of image will hide.

Answer (score 0):

Try with background-size property.